# Poisson regression for count data - predictions

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, prediction

This is probably an elementary error in either my understanding or my R implementation: I am trying use a Poisson model to make some predictions. The original data is discrete count data. I would expect the predictions to also be discrete outcomes (e.g. 39, 40, 41). Instead - the predictions include decimals (41.2) - which seems odd for count predictions / the Poisson distribution. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
warpbreaks
breaksmodel<-glm(breaks~wool*tension, warpbreaks, family=poisson)
predict(breaksmodel,warpbreaks,type="response")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Predictions from a Poisson model are the mean parameter of a Poisson distribution, which is not constrained to be an integer. (Think of the old "the average family has 2.4 children" conundrum.) *Simulated outcomes* from your model using those predicted means  will of course be integers: for the predictor combination giving a predicted mean of 41.2 you might well get 45, 39, 42, or 40 as simulated outcomes.